# MySQL backend & Access (.accdb, 2013) Frontend Auto Increment Issue

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a MySQL database that the tables are each set up with an ID field which is an auto increment and primary key. When I use access to link to this database and tables in table design view in Access the fields are listed as the primary key but the type is number, not auto number. This is causing an issue when trying to create a new record because the ID field is not being populated automatically. Please help.

Comment: it will only populate after insert or after update.. it won't populate while inserting or before inserting.. if its not populating after insert, check MySQL if AI is ticked for that column.

Answer (score 1):

The autonumbering property of the id fields is set at the level of the MySQL database. Access might not be able to identify this property when connected to the back end database. This is why it considers it as a number, and not an autonumber, field.

This said, when inserting new records in the MySQL database, you do not need to send any value for the id field, so the MySQL engine automatically fills it with the updated autonumber value.